# Including the worksheet title in the spreadsheet

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script

I have a daily worksheet titled 07.09.17 Thursday, there are 4 sheets inside that I would like to add 07.09.17 (or the day of the sheet) in cell A1?  Obviously every day is dated accordingly but when running a back up script I want it to refer to cell A1 as the date to be entered into the archive sheet.  I have everything else working except this. I can't us =Now() or =Today() as I make the sheets up to 3 months in advance as we have some bookings that far in advance, also they are not only accessed on that day but many days.However the day of the backup is the date of the sheet.With many staff I don't want to have to trust them to do (ctrl) +; to insert date for each sheet manually.
Thank you for your help.

```
    function onOpen() { // This function adds a custom menu to the spreadsheet (Backup to archive) so you can run the script from there.
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('Backup to archive')
    .addItem('timeStamp','dataBackup')
    .addToUi();
    }

function timeStamp() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
     var sheetNames = ['AM trip', 'PM trip', 'Pool / Beach', 'Night Dive'];
    .setActiveCell()
    .setValue(new Date());
}

  function dataBackup() {
  var inputSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var archiveSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('146WU8RghfFqlCpCSX7n6kBAKOyxcpVKt14yhVfvYz-g');
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var sheetNames = ['AM trip', 'PM trip', 'Pool / Beach', 'Night Dive'];
  for (var i = 0; i < sheetNames.length; i++) {

    var inputSheet = inputSS.getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]);
    var archiveSheet = archiveSS.getSheetByName(sheetNames[i]);

    var date = inputSheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
    var data = inputSheet.getRange('E7:U37').getValues().filter(function(row) { return row[0] !== '' || row[1] !== ''});

    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
        data[x].splice(0, 0, date);
    }
    var getDate = archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValue();
    var maxRowLength = data.reduce(function(length, row) { return Math.max(length, row.length); }, 0);
    var date = new Date(date); 
    var getDate = new Date(getDate);
    if (getDate.getDate() != date.getDate() || getDate.getMonth() != date.getMonth()) {     

        if (data.length != 0) {
            archiveSheet.insertRowsAfter(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), data.length);
            archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, maxRowLength).setValues(data);
        } else {
            archiveSheet.insertRowsAfter(archiveSheet.getLastRow(), 1);
            archiveSheet.getRange(archiveSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 2).setValues([[date, 'No Data']]);
        }
    }

  }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the sheets that you want this in are in the same spreadsheet then all you have to do is go to A1 and enter this `=nameOfSpreadsheet()` Yes, I know it's customary to capitalize all of the letters but I generally swim against the currents of following customs. You may capitalize all of them if you wish.

```
function nameOfSpreadsheet()
{
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName();
}
```

All of course you will have to put the function into a project in your script editor.  I keep my custom functions like this in a separate project from other functions.

I didn't pay attention to removing the week day so I find that this will work for that and now you just get the date.

```
function nameOfSpreadsheet()
{
  var s=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName().replace(/(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}).*/,'$1');
  return s;
}
```

This is the function in the code editor:

[image]

And this is how it's deployed:

[image]

The title of the spreadsheet is 09.09.17 Saturday

Comment: thanks for that, where would I add that script in the daily sheet script? I have amended the question with the script for clarification.

Comment: I don't know.  It's your script. Where do you want to put the title of the spreadsheet?

Comment: Sorry cell A1 in 4 of the 6 sheets in the spreadsheet, named 'Sheet 1', 'sheet 2', 'sheet 3' and finally for variety 'sheet 5'!

Comment: Yes, the tabs are labelled Am Trip, PM trip etc but the worksheet name is the date of the trips named 09.09.17 Saturday etc for everyday of the year. In cell A1 I would like just 09.09.17 but not the day? I have run the function you mentioned above but all i get is an error "loading data...." in cell A1. Is it the periods in the date that are the issue?  if so how can I format to ensure it works?

Comment: I don't know let me try this in another spreadsheet with such a name.

Comment: I put it in a new spreadsheet and named it 9.09.17.  I went to the script editor and ran the function once to authorize it and then put `=getSpreadsheetTitle()` in A1 and it came up with 9.09.17